How can I implement a hashmap to nested struct, using boost::fpr::for_each_field_with_name
I want to create a method to go to and from nested structs, each only holding double values like so:
struct Location {
    double lat;
    double lon;
};


struct Person {
    double height;
    double age;
    double weight;
    Location location;
};

int main()
{
    // Create a Person instance
    Person person = {1.75, 30, 70, {1, 2}};

    std::unordered_map<std::string, double> hashmap;
    to_hashmap(person, hashmap);
    
    std::cout << "Hashmap Values:\n";
    for (const auto& [key, val] : hashmap) {
        std::cout << key << ": " << val << std::endl;
    }

    // // // Reconstruct struct from hashmap
    Person restored_person = from_hashmap<Person>(hashmap);
    
    std::cout << "Restored Person:\n";
    std::cout << "Height: " << restored_person.height << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age: " << restored_person.age << "\n";
    std::cout << "Weight: " << restored_person.weight << "\n";
    std::cout << "Location - Latitude: " << restored_person.location.lat << "\n";
    std::cout << "Location - Longitude: " << restored_person.location.lon << "\n";

    return 0;
}

I have the code to convert a nested struct into a hashmap, which is working fine (commenting out the struct restruction code), which looks like:
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>
#include <boost/pfr/core_name.hpp>


// Helper function to check if a type is a struct (excluding built-in types)
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_struct_v = !std::is_fundamental_v<std::decay_t<T>> && !std::is_pointer_v<std::decay_t<T>> && !std::is_reference_v<std::decay_t<T>>;

// Helper function to check if a type is double
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_double_v = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, double>;

template <typename T>
concept DefaultConstructible = std::is_default_constructible_v<T>;

template <typename T>
void to_hashmap(const T& value, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& result, const std::string& prefix = "");

template <typename T>
void to_hashmap(const T& value, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& result, const std::string& prefix) {
    boost::pfr::for_each_field_with_name(value, [&](std::string_view name, const auto& field_value) {
        // Create the full name by combining the prefix with the current field name
        std::string full_name = prefix.empty() ? std::string(name) : prefix + "." + std::string(name);
        
        std::cout << "Processing field: " << full_name << std::endl;

        if constexpr (is_struct_v<decltype(field_value)>) {
            // Recursively call to_hashmap for nested structs
            to_hashmap(field_value, result, full_name);
        } else if constexpr (is_double_v<decltype(field_value)>) {
            // Only assign if the field is a double
            result[full_name] = field_value;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Skipping field: " << full_name << " (not double)" << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

Which for converting a struct to a hashmap, outputs:
Processing field: height
Processing field: age
Processing field: weight
Processing field: location
Processing field: location.lat
Processing field: location.lon
Hashmap Values:
height: 1.75
age: 30
location.lat: 1
weight: 70
location.lon: 2

However, I am struggling to write the inverse of that. Is it possible to write a from_hashmap method to convert a hashmap of values to a struct using boost::fpr::for_each_field_with_name.
(Note,  boost::fpr::for_each_field_with_name is not yet in boost, you will have to clone at https://github.com/boostorg/pfr and copy over the boost folder in /include)

I think for_each_field_with_name is not officially available yet. Its not defined in boost 1.86: https://godbolt.org/z/K97fnP3hc

Yep, Ive added that info at the bottom of my question, Ive worked out how to do it for this simple usecase now anyway so i'm going to add an answer now

I got a method to work, making a struct which can handle the different expected types:
struct from_hashmap_handle_type {
    // Handle case when the field is a double
    template<typename T>
    void handle_double(const std::string& key, const std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& hashmap, T& field_value) {
        auto it = hashmap.find(key);
        if (it != hashmap.end()) {
            field_value = it->second;
        }
    }

    // Handle case when the field is a class type (using recursion)
    template<typename T>
    void handle_class(const std::string& key, const std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& hashmap, T& field_value) {
        boost::pfr::for_each_field_with_name(field_value, [&](std::string_view name, auto& class_field_value) {
            std::string full_name = key.empty() ? std::string(name) : key + "." + std::string(name);
            handle_field(full_name, hashmap, class_field_value);
        });
    }

    // Main dispatcher function to determine the type
    template<typename T>
    void handle_field(const std::string& key, const std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& hashmap, T& field_value) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
            handle_double(key, hashmap, field_value);
        } else {
            handle_class(key, hashmap, field_value);
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
void from_hashmap(const std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& hashmap, T& result) {
    from_hashmap_handle_type handler;

    boost::pfr::for_each_field_with_name(result, [&](std::string_view name, auto& field_value) {
        std::string key = std::string(name);
        handler.handle_field(key, hashmap, field_value);
    });
}

Which you can then call like...
    Person restored_person;
    from_hashmap(hashmap, restored_person);
    
    std::cout << "\nRestored Person:\n";
    std::cout << "Height: " << restored_person.height << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age: " << restored_person.age << "\n";
    std::cout << "Weight: " << restored_person.weight << "\n";
    std::cout << "Location - Latitude: " << restored_person.location.lat << "\n";
    std::cout << "Location - Longitude: " << restored_person.location.lon << "\n";

